# what is wrong with my squid configuration?

Tags: proxy, http, squid, http-proxy

I installed squid3 on my Debian server and replaced `squid.conf` with this code

```
acl manager proto cache_object
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8
acl localnet src myip/24
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80 #http
acl Safe_ports port 21 #ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443 #https
acl Safe_ports port 70 #gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210 #waim
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535 #unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280 #http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488 #gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591 #filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777 #multiling http

acl CONNECT method CONNECT

http_access allow manager localhost
http_access allow localnet
http_access deny manager
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny to_localhost

icp_access deny all
htcp_access deny all

# block all other access
http_access deny all

http_port 3128
# heirarchy_stoplist cgi-bin ?
access_log /var/log/squid3/access.log squid

#Suggested default:
refresh_pattern ^ftp: 1440 20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher: 1440 0% 1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0% 0
refresh_pattern . 0 20% 4320
# Leave coredumps in the first cache dir
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid3
```

I restarted squid but I'm unable to access (it says `Access Denied`).

Answer (score 0):

The `myip/24` entry in your config - is that intentionally obfuscated?

```
acl localnet src myip/24
```

Or is that replaced in the live/actual config with a proper IP address range?

If that's not intentional, try and replace that with your LAN network range in CIDR notation, restart squid, and try again.